# Overlapping clustering in R

Tags: r, regression, cluster-computing, correlation, overlapping

I have a bunch of observations that are correlated with each other in two different ways, so I'd like to perform logistic regressions but try to account for the correlations among observations to get the best standard errors that I can. I think I can potentially do that via overlapping clusters? E.g., if observations 1-4 relate to one subject and observations 5-8 relate to another subject, I can cluster 1-4 together and 5-8 together. But if, for example, observations 1 and 5 are correlated in some way, as are observations 2 and 6, 3 and 7, and 4 and 8, I'd want to cluster that way too (i.e., so each observation belongs to 2 clusters).

Is it possible to perform logistic regression, ideally in R but if not in some other accessible language, for data in overlapping/non-exclusive clusters? If so, how would I do it?

If I use glm and ignore the correlations, then my understanding is that the standard errors I get may be incorrect. I think gee can generally be used if I'm just looking for an average population effect, but I think that only allows me to use non-overlapping/exclusive clusters. I'm stumped for overlapping/non-exclusive clusters.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This seems like is more a methodology question than a programming question. It would fit better at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I can check that out. I was mostly just hoping if anyone knew of some way in R (or something similar) to do overlapping clusters.